# Include JavaParserJsonSerializer in JavaParser Maven Project?

Tags: java, maven, javaparser

I'm attempting to include the [`JavaParserJsonSerializer`](https://www.javadoc.io/doc/com.github.javaparser/javaparser-core-serialization/latest/com/github/javaparser/serialization/JavaParserJsonSerializer.html) class in my Java program using the [JavaParser](https://github.com/javaparser/javaparser) library. I'm using the latest JavaParser v3.25.9, and the IntelliJ IDE v2023.2.5.

I wanted to compile [one of the basic `JavaParserJsonSerializer` examples](https://github.com/javaparser/javaparser/blob/master/javaparser-core-serialization/src/test/java/com/github/javaparser/serialization/JavaParserJsonSerializerTest.java). However, while I am able to import the core JavaParser classes such as [`CompilationUnit`](https://www.javadoc.io/doc/com.github.javaparser/javaparser-core/3.2.5/com/github/javaparser/ast/CompilationUnit.html) (located in `com.github.javaparser.ast`), I am not able to import any of the classes in the `com.github.javaparser.serialization` package (including `JavaParserJsonSerializer`) in any of my project files. Instead I'm simply prompted with:

```
Cannot resolve symbol 'serialization'
```

I am including the JavaParser library in my Maven project via the following dependency in the project's `pom.xml` file:

```
<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.github.javaparser</groupId>
        <artifactId>javaparser-core</artifactId>
        <version>3.25.9</version>
    </dependency>
</dependencies>
```

I am not very experienced with Maven's methods of handling dependencies, but I initially assumed that I would need to add the `com.github.javaparser.serialization` dependency in addition to the core `com.github.javaparser` dependency. However, that does not appear to be the issue. Attempting to change the dependencies like such:

```
<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.github.javaparser</groupId>
        <artifactId>javaparser-core</artifactId>
        <version>3.25.9</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.github.javaparser.serialization</groupId>
        <artifactId>javaparser-core-serialization</artifactId>
        <version>3.25.9</version>
    </dependency>
</dependencies>
```

Results in:

```
Dependency 'com.github.javaparser.serialization:javaparser-core-serialization:3.25.9' not found
```

What is the proper way to import the JavaParser classes from the `com.github.javaparser.serialization` package, such as `JavaParserJsonSerializer`?

Thanks for reading my post, any guidance is appreciated.

Comment: ur maven groupId using `com.github.javaparser`
see [Maven](https://central.sonatype.com/artifact/com.github.javaparser/javaparser-core-serialization/overview) 
and [javaparser](https://github.com/javaparser/javaparser)

Comment: @Ken.Zhang thanks for your reply; this solved my issue. You should post that as the answer, I'll accept it.

Comment: ok, I've submitted it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

ur maven groupId using com.github.javaparser see [Maven](https://central.sonatype.com/artifact/com.github.javaparser/javaparser-core-serialization/overview) and [javaparser](https://github.com/javaparser/javaparser)

Comment: For some further elaboration, my issue was the fact that the `groupId` field of the javaparser serializer dependency was `com.github.javaparser.serialization`, when it instead needed to be just `com.github.javaparser`.